# How do you use the GPU offscreen render API in 2.8?

Tags: python, scripting, gpu-module

For a [while now](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_2/gpu.offscreen.html) in blender there has been this GPU Off-screen renderer; however, I think it has changed a bit in 2.8, and plus, I never even knew how to use it before.

Basically I want to be able to render a video animation using the offscreen rendering API, specifically the "[3D View into Texture](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/gpu.html#rendering-the-3d-view-into-a-texture)" example, here is the code from the docs on the website:

```
import bpy
import bgl
import gpu
from gpu_extras.presets import draw_texture_2d

WIDTH = 512
HEIGHT = 256

offscreen = gpu.types.GPUOffScreen(WIDTH, HEIGHT)


def draw():
    context = bpy.context
    scene = context.scene

    view_matrix = scene.camera.matrix_world.inverted()

    projection_matrix = scene.camera.calc_matrix_camera(
        context.evaluated_depsgraph_get(), x=WIDTH, y=HEIGHT)

    offscreen.draw_view3d(
        scene,
        context.view_layer,
        context.space_data,
        context.region,
        view_matrix,
        projection_matrix)

    bgl.glDisable(bgl.GL_DEPTH_TEST)
    draw_texture_2d(offscreen.color_texture, (10, 10), WIDTH, HEIGHT)


bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw, (), 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')
```

Although this works great for making a texture, it doesn't explain how to use this to save the image, I want to eventually implement an interface that will save the image, or store it into some kind of base64 image buffer (To send to a server) to render faster / real time, but even more importantly: it doesn't explain how to change the resolution of the output, so:

**How exactly do I render (e.g. save onto disk OR store in buffer) a simple animation (I.e, image sequence) using the GPU Off-Screen Render API, at any given resolution (even 1920 / 1080) in Blender 2.8?**

Comment: Isn't there an example on same page that creates a texture image of circles?

Comment: @batFINGER yes, there is and it gives some important insights - I managed to write the 3D view into an image. However, I can not execute `offscreen.draw_view3d(...)` without `bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw, ...)`, which makes my current state a bit messy ...

Answer (score 2):

The following code shows the essential steps to write the 3D view into a Blender image.

The main caveat is that the currently `offscreen.draw_view3d()` is called within `draw()` using `bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add`. 
This has a few consequences:

- one must ensure that the 3D view is redrawn, for example by clicking onto some object in the 3D view
- the function is called multiple times

When moving `offscreen.draw_view3d()` outside of `draw()`, I received  the following error message: `TypeError: expected 'SpaceView3D' type found 'SpaceTextEditor' instead`. So currently, I'm stuck setting the correct context. Any help would be highly appreciated - I'll update the post correspondingly.

```
import bpy
import bgl
import gpu
from mathutils import Matrix
from gpu.types import GPUOffScreen


def draw():

    print('draw: bpy.context.area.type',  bpy.context.area.type)
    global write_view_3d

    if write_view_3d:

        # Write the image into the offscreen buffer
        offscreen.draw_view3d(
            scene=scene,
            view_layer=bpy.context.view_layer,
            view3d=bpy.context.space_data,
            region=bpy.context.region,
            view_matrix=view_matrix,
            projection_matrix=projection_matrix)

        buffer = bgl.Buffer(bgl.GL_BYTE, width * height * 4)
        bgl.glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, bgl.GL_RGBA, bgl.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer)

        if(image_name not in bpy.data.images):
            bpy.data.images.new(image_name, width, height)
        image = bpy.data.images[image_name]
        image.pixels = [v / 255 for v in buffer]

        print('write_view_3d', write_view_3d)
        write_view_3d = False
    else:
        print('write_view_3d', write_view_3d)

image_name = "Result"
scene = bpy.context.scene
render = bpy.context.scene.render
width = bpy.context.region.width
height = bpy.context.region.height

offscreen = gpu.types.GPUOffScreen(width, height)
view_matrix = scene.camera.matrix_world.inverted()
projection_matrix = scene.camera.calc_matrix_camera(
    bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get(), 
    x=width,
    y=height)

write_view_3d = True
current_draw_handler = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(
    draw, (), 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')
```

Comment: interesting, any way to get the resolution to 1920 x 1080 even if the 3d view window is smaller than that?

Comment: resize the image.

Comment: @batFINGER how would one do that? and does that change the quality of the scene itself?

Comment: No it resizes the image IIRC its `Image.resize(x, y)` of a blender image instance. Wont be the resolution just the size.... previous comment needed a question mark.

Comment: Another option would be to use `bpy.ops.render.opengl`

Comment: @batFINGER if so, then that doesn't answer the question

Comment: @Mr.EpicFail that is no where near real time rendering

Comment: The reason for this is the line `image.pixels = [v / 255 for v in buffer]`. The reason for this is stated [here](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/gpu.html#copy-offscreen-rendering-result-back-to-ram). So I guess it is not possible to do this faster at the moment. Quote: _Currently almost all of the execution time is spent in the last line. In the future this will hopefully be solved by implementing the Python buffer protocol for bgl.Buffer and bpy.types.Image.pixels (aka bpy_prop_array)_

Comment: If you need a specific size for your output, I recommend to use `bpy.ops.render.opengl`. This should be faster as well and can be used outside of the draw method above.